# error when trying to git clone and launch locally

Tags: node.js, react-redux

i've cloned a few projects successfully, but am having trouble with the latest one...see below

i've done the following (and have repeated the process in deleting and starting from scratch a few times now) 
- git clone, cd / "project x", yarn install

BUT when i try to "yarn start", i run into errors...

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.1.0 open:src: `babel-node tools/server.js development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the trading-app@0.1.0 open:src script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

*note: i'm a little new at this, so any step by step guide would be appreciate!!

Comment: Have you tried `npm install` & then `npm start` ?

Comment: yup, same error after 'npm start'. The Start app in dev mode... is clean, but then when it goes to Starting Express server in development mode... the errors pop up...

Comment: would anyone else have any other ideas as to why this isn't working?
what I am trying to accomplish is the following...

1) git clone (SUCCESS)
2) cd into project and npm install (looks successful)
3) npm start (errors above)

Comment: You need to post your `package.json` here. Or whats in your `npm start` command.

Comment: @BhushanBabar thanks for the note! here's the package.json link [https://github.com/arshdkhn1/trader/blob/master/package.json] and the only other comment I received was that "when you run the app, server might crash because it needs some environment variables that I was supplying through a .env file. You can manually comment the code and change js code accordingly a bit to make the app run." - would appreciate any help here as I am a bit lost on what needs to be changed or added at this point...thanks all!

Comment: i know this is an issue with needing the environment variables / server in place (.env file), but would appreciate any thoughts on how to go about this...

the error occurs during the "Starting Express server in development mode..."